# How do you specify a bold font to use for Computer Concrete?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, packages, math-fonts

I'm using the Computer Concrete fonts using `\usepackage{concmath}`. I really like how text and math are rendered using this font; but a major downside is that it does not have bold variants, and falls back to Computer Modern instead. I found a font I'd like to use as a replacement for Computer Modern as a bold font—Kerkis, through `\usepackage{kerkis}`. **Using pdfLaTeX, not XeLaTeX**, is there a way to specify Kerkis as the bold font for my document, and keep Computer Concrete as the font for the rest of the text and math? A MWE would be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend `fontspec` package.

Comment: `fontspec` would require `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`, though. (Just saying. I would recommend it as well.)

Comment: Kerkis fonts use a nonstandard encoding: you need to be aware that accents are in strange places. Also, Concrete fonts are not available in Type1 format, unless you use T1 encoding.